# How A Military Background Can Affect Getting a CS Job

Tags: job-search

If someone served in the US military as a Programmer and IT specialist and received education on Computer Science while serving, is this seen as sub-par experience compared to having private sector experience? Do IT and CS companies see a previous military career as a negative?

Comment: Not to my experience.   You might look into government jobs as will have somewhat similar bureaucracy.  Still VTC as opinion based.

Comment: I am sure troubleshooting is one area where a military person can shine. :)

Comment: I cannot see why that would matter, and as @MaskedMan pointed out troubleshooting should be an area to shine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't make a difference. If you have recognised qualifications then there is no need to even say you got them in the military.

If your training was all on specialised equipment and procedures, then, yes, that would be a concern. I have seen this, but only with engineers.